# Resampling data by week

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have a time series dataset of 100 users looking at 365 days of transactions. The dataframe is currently set up like the following:

```
      date    2018-04-01 2018-04-02 2018-04-03 2018-04-04  2018-04-05 ...
userid
   1              0          0             0        0          13.40
   2            12.32        0             0        0           3.60
   3            11.32        0           14.22      0            0
   4              0          0             0        0           9.87
   5              0          0           19.52      0            0
  ...
```

I want to resample this to 52 weeks, taking the sums of the transactions every 7 days. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this there is a method [`DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
#df.columns=pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df_resamp=df.resample('W',axis=1).sum()
print(df_resamp)

        2018-04-01  2018-04-08
userid                        
1             0.00       14.50
2            12.32        5.60
3            11.32       17.22
4             0.00       12.87
5             0.00       21.52
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `weekofyear`:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.weekofyear, axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
date       13     14
userid              
1        0.00  13.40
2       12.32   3.60
3       11.32  14.22
4        0.00   9.87
5        0.00  19.52
```

You can also groupby every seven days:

```
(df.groupby(np.repeat(np.arange(df.shape[1]), 7)[:df.shape[1]],
            axis=1)
   .sum()
)
```